# Bitcoin payment integration using Coinbase API in PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api

Please ignore my inaccuracy while asking question. I want Bitcoin to be one of payment methods on my website. 
There are three types of membership. I want member to pay amount depending upon the plan (s)he selected.
Can someone please help me with the steps of incorporating the same and how can I get and use the response received after success / failure of transtaction. 
I need exact steps as I am newbie. Coinbase API is not helping me at all. :(
https://www.coinbase.com/docs/api/overview

Comment: Have you even tried doing anything?

Comment: @nahtnam: That's why I am asking question here because I am not getting way to get started.

Comment: Coinbase has made a wrapper for PHP. https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php This should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

*RE> clicked on Bitcoin button. Open wallet link is saying address is not understood.*

I checked, [Gourl.io](https://gourl.io) use standard  Bitcoin URI scheme (BIP21).

`bitcoin:<address>[?amount=<amount>][?label=<label>][?message=<message>]`

On the desktop all of Armory, Electrum and MultiBit respond to Bitcoin URI clicks in a browser -

https://gourl.io/bitcoin-payment-gateway-api.html?gourlcryptolang=en#gourlcryptolang

Comment: Mention Some more details @A Amir

Answer (score -2):

You can do like on that example - http://goo.gl/858bMw

with Bitcoin Payment API https://github.com/cryptoapi/Payment-Gateway

Comment: I visited the example page, and clicked on Bitcoin button. Open wallet link is saying address is not understood.

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer the question concerning Coinbase.